# BASIC language - novice

Tags: basic, realbasic

Can anyone suggest a good book or site for learning BASIC language?

I would like to try my hands on Realbasic but all that I read about this software is about the user interfaces.  Not much is available on how to code.  Thank you and best regards.

Comment: Why are you trying to learn BASIC?

Comment: actually, I'm trying to figure out how to enter codes in Real Studio, which uses realbasic language.  So, that's why I'd like to learn BASIC.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of resources available to learn Real Studio.  First, there are the hundreds of example programs that come with the IDE itself.  They are a good place to start poking around so you can discover the questions you don't know you have yet.

The Association of REALbasic Professionals has a source code repository that contains over 150 tutorials and projects for Real Studio.  They also have conference videos and other miscellaneous resources.  They are at http://www.arbp.org.

My site has over 30 hours of Real Basic training videos at http://www.bkeeney.com.  Most of the sessions have an associated project file that you are free to peruse and use in your own projects.

Also take a look at VTC which has about 8 hours of video training available for real studio at http://www.vtc.com/products/Real-Studio-Tutorials.htm

Sadly, most of the books are pretty dated.  Real Studio is updated every 90 days which means that any book published today will already be dated in a few months.  There are some available from Amazon and I would search there:  http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=realbasic&x=0&y=0

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Could you please point to any specific link or article which deals with the codes one has to enter for a control to function.  I'm tired of searching high and low.  All the sites and tutorials I have seen so far only concentrate on the interface part of RB, which is very easy to understand.  How to go about learning to code is what stumps me.

Comment: Sure.  You can take a take a look at the tag cloud of all the training videos that I've created at http://www.bkeeney.com/realbasic-training-section/cloud-tag.  You should also take a look at the RB Wiki at http://docs.realsoftware.com/ and specifically the Language Reference part of it.  Also, I'd take a look at the examples folder as there are hundreds of examples.